# Pull historical secutities price from ISIN

Tags: python, web-scraping, finance, stock, isin

How can one pull historical securities (stocks & ETF's) price data in python from just the exchange and ISIN?

All the methods I've seen to do this first map it to the American system of using a code for the exchange and a ticker symbol for the security. There are two problems with that, some securities don't have American ticker symbols and others have the ticker symbol, but there isn't always a code to specify the exchange.

Currently, I am pulling tables from websites such as
https://www.boerse-online.de/etf/boersenplaetze/ishares-uk-property-etf-IE00B1TXLS18
&
https://www.finanzen100.de/zertifikate/sonstige/sonstiges-zertifikat-auf-bloomberg-brent-crude-subindex-total-return-wkn-a1n49p_H1225544336_49507519/

and then looking up the exchange in the table. But there are some issues with this too.

1. I cannot concatenate a website with the ISIN to get the webpage of the security as the security name is also in the URL, and so I must manually get the URL for each security.
2. For different securities, sometimes the formatting is different on the same website, so I must have different code for different securities.
3. Neither website has all exchanges for all securities, so I must manually find the security online first.
4. These websites don't give historical data as a table, only current price and some additional information.

As ISIN's are the internationally recognized way to identify a security and using it and the exchange seems to be the most obvious, simplest and, in many cases, the only way to specify a security on a particular exchange, I was surprised I couldn't find tools to do this.

Comment: ISINs are internationally recognized, but do not enjoy broad acceptance in the US.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. But since there are many places in the world that use them, I was surprised I couldn't find an existing solution to this.

Comment: Well, you can convert an ISIN beginning `US` to a CUSIP, but that will only get you so far, because what you really want are ticker symbols, and exchanges (and Bloomberg) generally want you to pay for CUSIP/ISIN-to-ticker conversion tables.

Comment: Why do you recommended converting to Tickers or CUSIP? The majority of the ISIN's I am looking at do not begin with "US" and are not domiciled in the US.
When I saw that that was how everyone else does it, I did try to do the same, but ran into problems because some of the securities don't have a ticker and the exchanges I am looking at are mostly in Europe. As the american system uses a code for the exchange too, I found that outside the US, for some smaller exchanges, there doesn't seem to be a code to specify the exchange. 
So if I cannot do it manually, there's no hope I can automate it.

Comment: By "ticker" I mean whatever your data source uses as a security identifier. In London it's a SEDOL, Reuters calls it a RIC,  Bloomberg calls them tickers. It looks to me as if what you are trying to do is to build your own Bloomberg. That's a worthy aim, but it may be more ambitious than you bargained for.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is download some data, I'm agnostic to the data source and method. But as far as I can tell, not all the securities I have are compatible with the Ticker system. I will look into this SEDOL system, being more local, it might have the smaller securities and exchanges I am looking at.
Thanks for the tip

Comment: Then you may also not know that there are substantial chunks of the market where the instruments don't have ISINs at all. One such is options on bond futures. That is because there are a lot of them, and every 3 months a whole bunch of them expire and get replaced by new ones, and if they had ISINs that would burn up all of the available numbers in a couple of years. Interest rate swaps don't have identifiers either, only coded descriptions, because every swap instrument is unique.

Comment: Good to know, but I am only looking at stocks and ETF's

Comment: Well, if it comes to that, DE0009652644 identifies not one but a family of ETFs (on Bund  futures) with different expiries.